# Separable closure of $k(Y)$ in $k(X)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $k $ be a not perfect field and $\operatorname{char}(k)=p>0$. Let $a \in k \setminus k^{p}$. Let $Y=\dfrac{X^{p^2}}{X^p+a}$. Prove that $[k(X):k(Y)]=p^2$, and the separable closure of $k(Y)$ in $k(X)$ is $k(X^p)$.

First, I used the polynomial $P=T^{p^2}-yT^p-ya$, but how to prove that $P$ is irreducible? I think in Luroth theorem.

Comment: This might just be my ignorance, but what exactly is $k^p$ here?

Comment: @Arthur The subset of $k$ that are power $p$ of an element of $k$.

Comment: Are you reading *Corps commutatifs et théorie de Galois* from Patrice Tauvel?

Comment: Yes i read patrice tauvel book. So, i have a lot of problems to resolve the exercices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As $X$ is a root of the polynomial $P(T)=T^{p^2}-YT^p-Ya \in k(Y)[T]$, we have $[k(X):k(Y)] \le p^2$. $Y$ is transcendental over $k$ as otherwise $X$ would be algebraic over $k$. This implies that $k[Y]$ is a [unique factorization domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain).

$Y$ is irreducible in $k[Y]$ and $Y^2$ doesn't divide $Ya$. We can apply [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion#Generalization) to conclude that $P$ is irreducible over $k[Y]$ and also over $k(Y)$ according to [Gauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)). Finally $[k(X):k(Y)] = p^2$ and $P$ is the minimal polynomial of $X$ over $k(Y)$.

Denote $K = k(Y)$. The separable closure $K_s$ of $K$ in $k(X)$ is the set of elements of $k(X)$ which are separable over $K$. It is a separable extension of $K$ such that $K \subset K_s \subset k(X)$. In fact $K_s \neq k(X)$ as $X$ is inseparable over $K$ as the derivative of $P$ is equal to zero. Therefore $[K_s : K]$ belongs to $\{1, p \}$ as it divides $p^2$ and is not equal to $p^2$.

In a similar way as above, we can prove that the polynomial $Q(T)=T^p-YT-Ya \in K[T]$ is irreducible over $K$. $X^p$ is a separable root of $Q$ as $Q'(T)=-Y \neq 0$. Therefore we have $k(X^p) \subset K_s$ and finally $K_s=k(X^p)$ as $[k(X^p):k(Y)]=p$.

Comment: What a great solution! Thanks, but why $[K_s: k(y)]=p$?

Comment: I have another problem, we dont use $k$ is imperfect field? Thanks.

Comment: That is a good comment! I'm reading again my proof... but I don't see where this is useful. I'll look closer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: the question is to find the relative separable closure. The same exercice of patrice tauvel is in Bourbaki Ch of commutative fields exercice 7-2).

Comment: Yes I understand now and added elements in my proof towards this point. However, I still don't see why $a \notin k^p$ is relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98110/discussion-between-naoufal-bouchareb-and-mathcounterexamples-net).